# Binding multiple objects to a List<t>

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to bind my model.List NewReportDetails normally this is  not an issue.  In this case I have users adding additional models to the list via Ajax. When they hit Submit I can see the  default model but the List is empty.

Here is my Models

1. Index Model:

   ```
   public List<ShiftReport> ShiftReportList { get; set; }
   public ShiftReport NewReport { get; set; }
   public List<ShiftReportDetail> NewReportDetails { get; set; }
   public List<UserListsForSignatures> ListOfNames { get; set; }
   public List<ProductCodes> ProductsList { get; set; }
   public List<EquipList> Equipment { get; set; }
   ```
2. ShiftDetailDetail Model:

   ```
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int ReportID { get; set; }
   public int? Area { get; set; }
   public string AreaDecoded { get; set; }
   public int? Product { get; set; }
   public string ProductString { get; set; }
   public int Equipment { get; set; }
   public string EquipmentString { get; set; }
   public string Comment { get; set; }
   public string TypeOfTrouble { get; set; }
   public string CounterMeasure { get; set; }
   public string Time { get; set; }
   public string Tag { get; set; }
   public string[] TagArray { get; set; }
   public int GroupCode { get; set; }
   public int TagDupFixer { get; set; }
   ```

Here is my controller
index:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
        ProductionSuperModel model = new()
        {
            ListOfNames = QualityHelper.GetAllTheNamesWithRoles(1),
            ProductsList = _repo.RetrieveProductList(),
            Equipment = _repo.RetrieveEquipmentList()

        };
        // tagduper = 1 means dont run the firsForloop this causes null pointer exeption if left  0
        return View(model);
       }
```

NewReportDetails

```
        public PartialViewResult NewReportDetail(int id)
        {
        ShiftReportDetail model = new()
        {
            ID = id,
            TagDupFixer = 1,
            EquipmentList = _repo.RetrieveEquipmentList(),
            ProductsList = _repo.RetrieveProductList()
        };
        return PartialView("_ReportDetail", model);
        }
```

AddReport

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddReport(ProductionSuperModel model) 
    {

        return Json(1);
    }
```

Index View

```
                 <div id="CreateReportDetail">
             </div>

             
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="SubmitAReport" class="btn btn-primary YearReview">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" id="closemodal" class="btn btn-secondary closemodal2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
```

Partial View

```
<div class="NewDetailDiv">
<input asp-for="@Model.ID" hidden />
<input asp-for="@Model.ReportID" hidden />
<input asp-for="@Model.GroupCode" hidden />
<div class="card mb-5" style="background-color: burlywood">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-floating mb-2 mt-2">
                    <select class="custom-select form-control ModelDisabled Taggable" multiple data-allow-clear="true" asp-for="@Model.TagArray">
                        <option selected disabled hidden value="">Equipment</option>
                        @foreach (var names in Model.EquipmentList)
                        {
                        <option value="@names.TagName">@names.TagName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <label>Equipment</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-floating mb-2 mt-2">
                    <select class="custom-select form-control ModelDisabled" asp-for="@Model.AreaDecoded">
                        <option selected>Please Select</option>
                        <option value="All">All</option>
                        <option value="Control Room">Control Room</option>
                        <option value="Dock">Dock</option>
                        <option value="Filling Building">Filling Building</option>
                        <option value="FillingRoom">FillingRoom</option>
                        <option value="HCA-1＆2">HCA-1＆2</option>
                        <option value="HCA1/2/NEU/U">HCA1/2/NEU/U</option>
                        <option value="HCA1/2/NEU/Utility?T-F">HCA1/2/NEU/Utility?T-F</option>
                        <option value="HCA-1">HCA-1</option>
                        <option value="HCA-2">HCA-2</option>
                        <option value="L598">L598</option>
                        <option value="L521">L521</option>
                        <option value="NEU/Utility/T-F">NEU/Utility/T-F</option>
                        <option value="W211">W211</option>
                        <option value="W112A">W112A</option>
                        <option value="Warehouse">Warehouse</option>
                    </select>

                    <label>Area</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-floating mb-2 mt-2">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Time" class="form-control ModelDisabled" type="text" placeholder="Time" />
                    <label>Time</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-floating mb-2 mt-2 ">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.ProductString" class="form-control dataLists  ModelDisabled" list="Products" placeholder="Product" />
                    <datalist id="PeopleDropdown">
                        <datalist id="Products">
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>
                            @foreach (var things in Model.ProductsList)
                            {
                            <option value="@things.ProductType">@things.ProductType</option>
                            }
                        </datalist>
                    </datalist>
                    <label>Product</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-floating mb-2 mt-2">
                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.TypeOfTrouble" class="form-control ModelDisabled" type="text" placeholder="Type of Trouble"
                              rows="3" style="height:100%;"></textarea>
                    <label>Type of Trouble</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-floating mb-2 mt-2">
                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.CounterMeasure" class="form-control ModelDisabled" type="text" placeholder="Counter Measure"
                              rows="3" style="height:100%;"></textarea>
                    <label>Counter Measure</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-floating mb-2 mt-2">
                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.Comment" class="form-control ModelDisabled" type="text" placeholder="Comment"
                              rows="3" style="height:100%;"></textarea>
                    <label>Comment</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#CreateReportDetail').load('/Production/NewReportDetail/0');
```

});

```
$(".AddMoreReportDetails").click(function () {

// find  the right div.
var counter = $('#ReportCounter');
var counterNo = +counter.val() + 1;
counter.val(counterNo);
$('#CreateReportDetail').append($('<div>').load('/Production/NewReportDetail/' + counterNo, function () {
    Tags.init(".Taggable");
}));
```

});

```
$(document).on("click", "#SubmitReportEdits", function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#EditReportForm").attr("action"),
    data: $("#EditReportForm").serialize(),
    success: function () {
        // close the modal
        // reload the table
        $('#ReviewReport').modal('toggle');
        $('#NotificationDiv').append( // change
            "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'> " + "Report has been edited. Thank you." +
            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>" + "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>" + "</button>" + "</div>"
        );
        
    }
});});
```

[image]
[image]

I do  see the information on the Request.Form.  However the model.List is null.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit --

Full Index.CShtml

```
@model PortalMVC.Models.Production.ProductionSuperModel;

<div id="NotificationDiv">
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-10 mb-3">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
                    <div class="dropdown float-left NAIIbg 
              RoundCorners">
                        <span data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
                           haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary 
                           dropdown-toggle NAIIbg border-0 
            BoxShadow" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data- 
       toggle="tooltip"  title="Create Report" aria- 
      haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fa fa-id-card" aria- 
         hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>

                        </span>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria- 
          labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                            <button class="dropdown-item 
           ReportType" type="button" value="MH">MH 
               Report</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item 
             ReportType" type="button" value="Maint">Maint 
       Report</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item 
        ReportType" type="button" value="HCA">HCA Report</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item 
      ReportType" type="button" value="PMCrew">PMCrew 
      Report</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item 
        ReportType" type="button" value="PAA">PA Report</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                            <input id="SearchInput" class="form- 
         control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria- 
           controls="EditTbl" />
                            <label>Search</label>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
              </div>
         </div>
             </div>
       <div class="w-100"></div>
     <div class="col-10" id="MainReportTbl">
     <!--Create a partial here-->
     <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align- 
      items:center;background-color:white">
        <div class="loader" id="loading2"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

full JS here --

```
import Tags from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lekoala/bootstrap5- 
tags@master/tags.js";
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#SearchInput").on("keyup", function () {
    $('#EditTbl').DataTable().search(
        $('#SearchInput').val()
    ).draw();
});
$('#CreateReportDetail').load('/Production/NewReportDetail/0');
 });
//  does the thing for modal for each of the rows.
// logic handler for  closing of modal.
$(".closemodal").click(function () {
$('#ReviewReport').modal('toggle');
});
$(".closemodal2").click(function () {
$('#CreateReport').modal('toggle');
});
 $(document).on("click", "#EditBtn", function () {
 $('.ModelDisabled').each(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
 });
 });
 // this calls the modal to open it for viewing.
 $(document).on("click", ".tableRowSelector", function () {
 var rowInfo = $(this).attr('name');
 $("#mod1").empty();
 // show the loading.
 $("#loading1").removeClass("d-none");
 $('#ReviewReport').modal('toggle');
 // rowinfo is working get this to the controller for  an ajax.
 $("#mod1").load("/Production/GetReport/" + rowInfo, function () {
    Tags.init(".Taggable");
    // hide the loading.
    $('.ModelDisabled').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
    $("#loading1").addClass("d-none");
    });
  }).find('tr').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  });
  // this is the one that updates  the modal if its being updated
  $(document).on("click", "#SubmitReportEdits", function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#EditReportForm").attr("action"),
    data: $("#EditReportForm").serialize(),
    success: function () {
        // close the modal
        // reload the table
        $('#ReviewReport').modal('toggle');
        $('#NotificationDiv').append( // change
            "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade 
     show' role='alert'> " + "Report has been edited. Thank you." +
            "<button type='button' class='close' data- 
     dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>" + "<span aria- 
     hidden='true'>&times;</span>" + "</button>" + "</div>"
        );            
    }
   });

   });

  // this is the function for adding new report
 $(document).on("click", "#SubmitAReport", function () {
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#AddReportForm").attr("action"),
    data: $("#AddReportForm").serialize(),
    success: function () {
        // close the modal
        // reload the table
        $('#CreateReport').modal('toggle');
        $('#NotificationDiv').append( // change
            "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible 
    fade show' role='alert'> " + "Report has been submitted. 
    Thank you." +
            "<button type='button' class='close' data- 
    dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>" + "<span aria- 
    hidden='true'>&times;</span>" + "</button>" + "</div>"
        );
    }
   });
   });
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#loading2").removeClass("d-none");
  $("#MainReportTbl").load('/Production/MainReportTable', 
  function () {
    var testing = $('#EditTbl').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "searching": true,
        columnDefs: [
            // Center align the header content of column 1
            { className: "dt-head-center", targets: [0, 1, 2, 3] 
         },
            { type: 'date', 'targets': [0] }
        ],
        order: [[0, , 'desc']]

    });
    $('#EditTbl_length').addClass('disabled');
    $('#EditTbl_filter').addClass('disabled');
    $("#loading2").addClass("d-none");
    });
    });

    // create the modal report stuff goes here.
  $(".ReportType").click(function () {
 var ReportType = $(this).val();
 var ModalTitle = ReportType + " Report";
 $('#ModalTitle').text(ModalTitle);
 // wipe the last report stuff.
 $('.NewDetailDiv').remove();
 // clean the counter
 $('#ReportCounter').val(-1);
 // hide show the right ones and show the stuff
 if (ReportType == 'HCA' || ReportType == 'MH') {
    $('#PMCrewPAMaint').addClass("d-none");
    $('#HCAMHReport').removeClass("d-none");
   }
 else {
    $('#PMCrewPAMaint').removeClass("d-none");
    $('#HCAMHReport').addClass("d-none");
}
Tags.init(".Taggable");
$('#CreateReport').modal('toggle');

 });
// this adds  new rows 
$(".AddMoreReportDetails").click(function () {

// find  the right div.
var counter = $('#ReportCounter');
var counterNo = +counter.val() + 1;
counter.val(counterNo);
 $('#CreateReportDetail').
 append($('<div>').
 load('/Production/NewReportDetail/' + counterNo, function () {
    Tags.init(".Taggable");
 }));
});
// this deletes row if they added tomany
$(document).on("click", ".DeleteThisDiv", function () {
// find the parent div
var testing = 
$(this).parent().closest('div')
.parent().closest('div').parent().closest('div');
 $(testing).remove(); 
});
```

Sorry  about the spacing it was a pain to get it all to look like code. I will try to find a good website so I can post the code there  for better reference.   Thank you.

Comment: Hi @tachidow, From your form data you can see your key name is `NewReport.Propertyname` which matches the `NewReport` model. For your `NewReportDetails`, it should match the key with `NewReportDetails[index].PropertyName`.  You just share part of code.  It is better for you to share the whole html with js if you still do not know how to modify your code.

Comment: Thank you Rena for the help.  I will definitely Edit to show the full index.cshtml, and JS file  Quick question if my model looks like partial view the only thing missing is an @model ... shiftDetailModel.   I will try to modify the partial view so it looks like newReportdetails[id].propertyNames.

Comment: I figured it out.   Thank you for the suggestion Rena.  added a new property to the model List<ShiftDetail> newreportdetial,  Then on the index it  looks like model.newreportDetail[Model.ID].PropertyName